# Play audio while seeking mp4 file in Swift

Tags: swift, audio, seek

I am using

```
self.player.seek(to: to, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero,
                                       toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)
```

to seek through videos, and they play smoothly according to slowly incremented 'to' CMTime. How can I achieve the same effect with audio in this file ? I would like to let user play sounds while changing to value with slider, so they can hear the video while scrolling and resume it in the selected moment.
Any advices ?

Thanks !

Comment: Read the file into the memory.

Comment: File is in the memory - there's no problem with playing sound on actual Play method. I want to be able to play sounds during seeking on pause.